# Right-click and IE F12 Developer Tools aren't working on modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working with a new-to-me project and I've got a modal window in the solution that won't allow me to right-click, pull up the alt-menu, or access F12 Developer Tools (only tested in IE via VS2010).

It's an ASP.NET MVC3 web app with Razor syntax, JS, jQuery, html, etc.

I've tried to see if there is JS that is restricting it, but I am suspicious that it has more to do with the modal window rather than a hard-coded override in the solution.

Anyone encounter this before or have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be that right-click is disabled because the modal is built with `window.showModalDialog()` and it's not actually bringing up a new window, instead it's just a viewer instance. Workaround would be to open the modal in a new window via `window.open()`.

Reference forum post: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3dfce9c2-8f4e-4dbc-a579-2f8d0999a595/cannot-right-clickandhold-to-select-and-copy-html-aspx-page-displayed-using?forum=netfxjscript